# Performance of chained Metal shaders versus a single shader?

Tags: ios, shader, metal

Practically speaking, how much overhead does chaining shaders have compared to if a single shader is used to do the same work?

In other words, is it preferable to chain shaders versus developing one monster shader? Or does the overhead from chaining them dictate to use as few shaders as possible?

As an example, consider @warrenm sample "Image Processing" [project](http://metalbyexample.com/fundamentals-of-image-processing/). There is a `adjust_saturation` shader chained to a `gaussian_blur_2d` shader. Would combining both shaders into a single shader significantly improve performance, or would it practically be the same?

Answer (score 0):

I would expect a significant amount of performance gain in your example of combining `adjust_saturation` to `gaussian_blur_2d` (assuming they do what their name's suggest).

From the GPU's point of view, both operations are pretty trivial in terms of the maths that need to be done, performance is going to be totally dominated by texture fetching and writing out results. I'd imagine that gaussian blur is doing bit more work because it presumably does multiple texture samples per output fragment. By combining the two shaders, you can eliminate entirely the texture fetching and writing cost of adjusting saturation.

I think by combining the two operations you could expect to make siginificant performance gains, somewhere around 10%-40% faster than chaining them. Bear in mind you might not see a difference in framerate because iOS is very active in managing the CPU/GPU clock speed, so it's really hard to measure things accurately.

Comment: I dare to doubt that. GPU texture caching and prefetching hides a lot of that sampling latency, and combining any blur kernel(especially a non separated 2D one) with anything really results in quite a lot of redundant work being done. The saturation adjustment probably converts from rgb to hsv and back which sure is not that much of instructions if done once per pixel but considering only a small 3x3 2D blur kernel you'd need to do that 9 times per pixel, of which 8 times are totally redundant...

Comment: You'd perform the saturation adjustment on the output of the blur kernel rather than the 9 inputs to it.

Comment: At least for mobile devices I agree with Columbo's answer, combining passes in a single shader is usually worth it. Not only for GPU but also for CPU, because for example on Android, switching current render target and performing draw calls has a non negligible CPU cost ... not sure what happens in the driver but I have seen render target switches costing around 0.2/0.3ms.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the size of texture and the size of cache. If you absolutely have to optimize it, it probably worths to combine them into a single shader. If you want to reuse your code, it makes sense to create a set of simpler shaders and combine them (just like my VideoShader project, https://github.com/snakajima/vs-metal).

By the way, when you combine multiple shaders, you'd better to create a single command buffer and encode all your shaders into that command buffer (instead of creating a command buffer for each shader). It allows Metal to do a certain set of optimizations.